# start qt on ubuntu14.04

Tags: c++, linux, qt

seems that I have multiple versions of QT pre-installed on my Ubuntu, but I haven't the qt designer. When I try to run QT designer I get the following error:

> designer: could not exec '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/designer':
>   No such file or directory

In file /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf I have the following lines:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
```

But in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin path there is no designer. How can I get the qt designer for qt?

Comment: Did you try sudo apt-get install qt4-designer?

Comment: By the way: I would recommend using the installer available at https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/ to get the most recent version of Qt.

Comment: I think you need to know how works linux first. But apt-get install do the work.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply install the designer package.
`sudo apt-get install qt4-designer`

If that package is already installed, obviously it's not installed properly.
You can do:
`sudo apt-get remove qt4-designer` 
or: `sudo apt-get remove qt4-designer --purge`

and then reinstall it.

On the other hand the versions you get using the packages are outdated.

So basically if you don't have a good reason for staying with 4.8 I would go to the download page and just grab the latest release, because you will get some nice functions and improvements along with it.

[Qt Download](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answers! I'm an Ubuntu newbie and I was a bit panicked too, so I didn't realize that a `sudo apt-get install qt4-designer` would be sufficient.
I installed the QT Creator 5.3 version, with these commands:

```
wget http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.3/5.3.0   /qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.3.0.run

chmod +x qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.3.0.run

./qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.3.0.run
```

It has the QT designer integrated